# C++ delegation? (Passing a function to be ran)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So i fairly new to c++ and i have come from a background from c# so this has been a big challenge, I struggling with a issue that is fairly simple in c# but seem to be a pain in c++

So i have a class TASK that has a function called ExecuteTask();

```
class Task
{
public:
    virtual void *ExecuteTask(void* foo);
};
```

This task is called but a Thread pool when added to a scheduled

What I'm looking to do is something like this

```
    Task *taskit = new Task();
    taskit->ExecuteTask(new void {

});
```

which i know is very simple in C# because you have delegation, you could use something along the lines of `+= delegate { // Do something }`

I am using Visual studio 2017 with MS standard library's and C++

Comment: Look up `std::function` and stop using `void*`. You're going about C++ the wrong way. Start anew without trying to make it look like C#.

Comment: If you have something like `+= delegate { // Do something }` then it only means that *delegation syntax is short* while overwhelming complexity boilerplate is hidden by compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to get a solution with std::function using

```
class Task
{
public:
     std::function<void(void)> ExecuteTask;
};
```

Then when i use it, i use:

```
Task *taskit = new Task();
taskit->ExecuteTask = [&]
{
    //Do something
};
```

Comment: It may be even better to provide a Task constructor that takes the std::function as param). Task task([]{...});

Comment: and maybe add a Task::run() member function that calls ExecuteTask (whose name should not start with uppercase as for the most common C++ naming conventions).

Comment: If you capture by reference, beware of dangling references in the captured variables. You need to guarantee that all the captured variables are still "live" whenever the task invokes the function.